# How can I download a youtube playlist with youtube-dl and make it a mp3-playlist?

Tags: mp3, youtube-dl

I want to download [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSzf4L_DltPLtcOJuLM-eSV5AzBQQIrPc) playlist but when I download it like `youtube-dl -i PLSzf4L_DltPLtcOJuLM-eSV5AzBQQIrPc` it doesn't write any playlist info in metadata. But most of the music players need playlists info to categorizing music files. Like cmus(I coudn't categorize my musics because lack of metadata). How can I do that?

Youtube-dl version: 2019.10.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`youtube-dl` has the `--add-metadata` option, but for it relies on the original video's metadata, which might be empty.

Your best bet would be to tag the file yourself using tools like `id3tool`:

`id3tool -a "<album name>" -r "<artist name>" -t "<song title>" <filename.mp3>`

You'll have to rely on the video name having everything you need, though.

If you want to go a step further, you could use an API like [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/developers) to get reliable metadata information based on the few variables available in the video's title.